# Is it possible to use rowspan as 1.5 in HTML tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, frontend

I want my row 3 to look like row 1 in appearance. Initially I tried to give rowspan="1.5", since it dint work i tried with above code. When I try to follow the procedure I followed in achieving row 1 results in misalignment.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0px;
}
td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
thead tr th {
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead style="border: 0px solid black;">
    <tr style="border=" 0px ">
      <th style="border: 0px ">Row 1</th>
      <th style="border: 0px ">Row 2</th>
      <th style="border: 0px ">Row 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tr> 
      <td rowspan="2 ">Row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td rowspan="3 ">Row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td >Row 1, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>       
      <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2 ">Row 3, cell 1</td>
      <td rowspan=" ">Row 3, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>     
      <td rowspan="3 ">Row 4, cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2 ">Row 5, cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 5, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 6, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? At least I'm a little confused.

Comment: Here is a Fiddle of your question: https://jsfiddle.net/2ejpx1dd/ . Please explain what you want.

Comment: Columns are rows or rows are columns ?

Comment: @thepio: Sorry for it. What i am trying to achieve is, i want row 3 to look like row 1 in appearance. I want "Row 1, cell 3" to occupy two rows just like how "Row 1, cell 1" is taking two rows using rowspan="2". Same way i want "Row 3, cell 3 " & "Row 5, cell 3" to occupy two rows as "Row 3, cell 1" and "Row 3, cell 1" respectively. Hopefully you got what i am trying to achieve here.

Comment: I think you are going to have to slow down and read what you type.  You are not making much sense.  can you draw what you want and add an image to your question?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a floating value for rowspan with html tables.

According to W3:

> [rowspan](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-rowspan) : This attribute specifies the number of rows spanned by
> the current cell. The default value of this attribute is one ("1").
> The value zero ("0") means that the cell spans all rows from the
> current row to the last row of the table section (THEAD, TBODY, or
> TFOOT) in which the cell is defined

**EDIT:**
When you use `<td rowspan="x">` you must remove `x` time the corresponding  on the next `<tr>`

Does this  suits you ?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">r1 c1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">r1 c2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">r1 c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">r2 c1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">r2 c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">r2 c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">r3 c1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">r3 c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```